# How to run Python commands in VS Code Terminal

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

I have installed latest Python Latest Python 3 (python-3.11.0-amd64) and latest VS Code (VSCodeUserSetup-x64-1.73.1). I also installed the Python Extension for Visual Studio Code.

I have selected the interpreter as:

[image]

But I am not able to run any Python Command in the terminal even as an administrator. No error and no complain but just empty line:

[image]

Why is this happening?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Has Python been added to your path? There's a checkbox for this in the dialogue when you install it, but if you didn't check that box, then its possible that Python hasn't been added to your path.

[system properties](https://i.stack.imgur.com/veOHH.png)
[image]

[edit path](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8jZkW.png)[image]

Answer (score 1):

Have you checked python path?

> system properties--->environment variables--->system variables--->path